How to get public IP of a Tasmota device without display?
I'm trying to determine the public IP address of a TASMOTA Smart PlugIn. I can send a request from the device to a corresponding website (e.g. www.ipchicken.com), but the TASMOTA does not have a screen. So the address is known, but i can't see it. Is there a way to have the IP sent to the caller via GET or Email or whatever? Unfortunately I can't find out about it via the router.
Thank you for any idea

I used the WebSend-Command of TASMOTA und called a PHP-Skript which writes the $_SERVER in a file. So i can read the IP-Adress.
Unfortunately, my router should be able to do port forwarding. So the IP is of no use to me. But that is another topic.
The qestion ist solved.

Assuming that you want to know the external IP of your network you should make your tasmota device visit an external service (i.e. https://api.ipify.org/ ),
you can than put the answer into a variable and send an email with this value.
script example (not tested)
>D 15
ip=""
day1=0
to="<me@gmail.com>"

>BS
WebQuery https://api.ipify.org/ GET

>E
ip=WebQuery

>S
print %ip%

; send at midnight
day1=day
if chg[day1]>0
then
=>sendmail [*:*:*:*:*:%to%:external IP]*
endif

>m
your external ip is %ip%
#

Firmware should have scripting functionality enabled and at least following defines:
USE_WEBSEND_RESPONSE
USE_SENDMAIL

The following parameters can be specified during compilation via #define directives in user_config_override.h:
- EMAIL_SERVER
- EMAIL_PORT
- EMAIL_USER
- EMAIL_PASSWORD
- EMAIL_FROM

